MSEdge options not opening profile I wanted, there are two profile work and profile
Whenever I ran the code, it simply creates new profile and not using current profile which I specified in code and not maximizing the Edge browser window.
System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "C:/Users/hanita/msedgedriver.exe");
EdgeOptions options= new EdgeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=C:/Users/hanita/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Edge/User Data");
options.addArguments("--profile-directory=Profile 2");
WebDriver driver= new EdgeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.google.com");

pom.xml:
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
     <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
     <version>4.26.0</version>
 </dependency>

Expecting to launch edge browser in maximized window.
